# configure server to handle a lot of requests

Tags: apache-2.2, website, vps, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [configure server to handle a lot of requests.](https://serverfault.com/questions/268729/configure-server-to-handle-a-lot-of-requests)

Hello all.

I have a website and we bought some advertisement on neobux.com.
We bought 1000 views hoping to get more users on the website.
We have a VPS with 1gb ram and 1gb burstable running apache. When we started
our add on the website we got around 1000 views in less than 1 minute.
As we see other wites can handle this sort of traffic but not ours.
Is there some sort of fix how we can view this because this sort of advertising
is needed to run the website. What it now does when we activate the website it
just loads very very slow and eventually goes to a blank screen.

Could anyone help,

Kind Regards
Damage

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx or lighttpd to serve static ads. Use the proxy features of Apache together with mod_rewrite to pass requests through to those HTTP servers or do it the other way around and use nginx/lighttpd to proxy through requests for dynamic content while serving static content directly.

Comment: That would work however we don't have static pages because it is up to the user to advertise our website to get more referrals. I forgot to mention we are running a Pay to Click script.

Comment: @damage000: simply edit it into your question. Nevertheless I have had good experience with nginx and lighttpd. They tend to be faster in many scenarios, though not all. Also keep in mind that some things simply won't work (say mod_dav_svn) without Apache currently.